# Auto-scroll to bottom of the result fetched by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm making a live chat website for my users. I'm fetching the chat messages via ajax.
Whenever I enter a new message, it does get added to the database and is displayed, but the scroll doesn't go to the bottom of the results.

Here's the example :-
When I type in a new message. The scroll doesn't go to the bottom.

[image]

When I manually scroll, then I get all the messages.

[image]

Here's my HTML div in which data is fetched via ajax.

```
<div id="chat">

</div>
```

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById('chat');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);
```

What would be the best way to get my result ?

Answer (score 2):

I did a little more than was asked for, but here's my answer. Please note that I did not include the AJAX function, and instead used the first message as a template, and just inserted that over and over to simulate new messages from AJAX. You would replace the line `$('#msg-template').clone()...` with your AJAX function, and the completion function that runs after AJAX should contain the next line: `if(autoScroll){ ScrollChat(); }`.

The fiddle has comments too (and some HTML and CSS): http://jsfiddle.net/mmwu1920/

```
var autoScroll = true;

function ScrollChat(){
    $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight).trigger('scroll');
}

function RefreshMessages(){
    $('#msg-template').clone().appendTo('#chat');
    if(autoScroll){ ScrollChat(); }
}
setInterval(RefreshMessages, 1000);

ScrollChat();

$('#chat').on('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() < this.scrollHeight - $(this).height()){
        autoScroll = false;
    }
    else{
        autoScroll = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the scroll position on the parent element (or the element that has the scrollbar):

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="chat">

  </div>

</div>
```

-

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById('container');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);
```